# fat-free image dump with quality factor

Tags: fat-free-framework

I try to specify the quality factor for Fatfree image processing. According to the documentation (https://fatfreeframework.com/image#dump) the dump method may take an integer value to specify the quality:

```
$img->dump($fileType, 75)   // $filetype is 'jpeg'
```

but I get the following error:

> imagejpeg(): Invalid 2nd parameter, it must [sic] a filename or a stream
>
> [...base.php:2032] Base->error(500,'imagejpeg(): Invalid 2nd parameter, it
>   must a filename or a stream')
>
> [...index.php:712] Image->dump('jpeg', 75)

Passing the quality factor as a string instead of int gets rid of the message but the resulting image is then empty.
(I know that jpeg and png dump use different values for quality/compression rate.)

Any idea where my error is? Thanks,

Comment: It seems that that error is triggered because there's *nothing* to be dumped. Can you share the beginning of your code?

Comment: The image object is created. [$img = new Image($source)] ...then resized and dumped. The code works when I omit the quality factor: $img->dump($fileType) ...dumps an image but unfortunately the default quality level is not sufficient in all cases.

Comment: There's a contradiction between the docs and the library. The method expects the same signature as the native [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function, so you should actually call `$img->dump($fileType, NULL, 75)`. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues/146) in order for the docs or the framework to get fixed.

Comment: Perfect, that is the solution! Can you use Answer so that I can mark it as the solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has been fixed in the framework, so beware that the expected syntax will change in the next release. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a contradiction between the docs and the library. The library was expecting an extra `NULL` argument, exactly as for the native [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues/146) now in the framework, so you can download the [edge](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core) version of the framework or wait for the next release.

As a summary:

**F3 <= 3.5.1**

```
$img->dump($fileType, NULL, 75)
```

**F3 > 3.5.1**

```
$img->dump($fileType, 75)
```

Comment: Thanks again, I have patched my version 3.5.1